Removing air vent in bedroom - Do I need to re-do it?
My old 1930's(ish) house has an air vent to the outside on one of the walls. We have had new vented windows installed so this isn't needed anymore. I took the vent off the wall, to be greeted by the cavity and the outer wall with the holes for the vent. I essentially just boarded up the inner wall and plastered over it.
I am now worried that I may have to re-do it. If water gets in to these holes and makes the insulation in the cavity wet, is this going to cause problems? Should I have blocked the outer wall (from the inside)? The external appears to be an air brick. I am in the UK

You certainly cannot leave a hole in the outer wall. Giving advice on what to do is hampered by not having pics.  Please post some of both the inside and outside.

Inside is all covered up now, I boarded it up, then levelled it out with a thin layer of polyfila. I'd have to wait until I got home to take a pic of outside nut it is essentially an air brick I think it's called

What you have is not usual in my area of the planet. that is why pics are very helpful. Someone else may recognise it and have experience in completing just what you want to do.

Does it help to add a location tag or something? I'm in the UK

Added relative information
